# Azure EventHub trigger is not working from remote desktop but working in personal computer

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

When i run this function in my personal computer it is working but when i use my office remote desktop  i get this error.

The listener for function 'funcEventHubTrigger' was unable to start.
[2022-07-18T22:30:09.385Z] The listener for function 'funcEventHubTrigger' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor: Encountered error while fetching the list of EventHub PartitionIds. System.Private.CoreLib: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: Can you TCP ping Event Hub's endpoint from both PCs? You can identify a network firewall issue by doing basic network checks.

Comment: These are the default port numbers 5671,5672 used by Azure Function Event Hub Triggers. So, could you please check your event hub namespaces on these ports in the [PortQrytool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=24009) whether the endpoints are blocking or not.

Comment: You may want to try updating your `host.json` to set the `transportType` to `amqpWebSockets`, this often can work around connectivity issues.   More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#hostjson-settings

Comment: As Jesse Squire said, you have to update transportType to the `AmqpWebSockets` so that it will create a tunnel over `TCP 443` port with then which is equivalent to `AMQP 5671` connection.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions Event Hub Trigger uses the default ports `5671`, `5672` and same is configured from the Event Hub trigger endpoint.

When you update the function's `host.json` for setting up the attribute `"transportType" : "amqpWebSockets"`, this often will create a tunnel over `TCP Port 443` with then which is equivalent to `AMQP 5671` connection.

Refer to the Azure [Event Hubs bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#hostjson-settings) for more information, provided by Microsoft.

Also, you can check your Event Hub namespaces on these ports in the [PortQrytool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=24009) whether the endpoints are blocking or not.